# No rerender when changing state by Object Spreader

Tags: reactjs, render, immutability

I am currently trying to clean up the code of my Todo app a bit and use more immutability. I have therefore replaced the code in the handleStatus function.

From this:

```
 handleStatus(event) {
      let newStatus;
      const changeState = event.status == 'done' ? newStatus = 'open' : newStatus = 'done';
      
      //Verkürzen Copy State
      let todo = event;
      todo.status = newStatus;

      this.setState({ todo });
     
    }
```

To this:

```
 handleStatus(event) {
      let newStatus;
      const changeState = event.status == 'done' ? newStatus = 'open' : newStatus = 'done';
      
      //Verkürzen Copy State
      let todo = {
        ...event,
        status: newStatus
      };

      this.setState({ todo });
     
    }
```

The status of the respective todo is changed but React no longer renders the corresponding part so that no change takes place in the browser.

Thank you for help

Here is the Full Code....
TodoTable (Parents):

```
import React from "react";
import { InputBar } from "./InputBar";
import { Todo } from "./Todo";

const emptyForm = {
  enterTodo: ""
  
};

export class TodoTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        enterTodo: "",
        todos: this.props.todos,
        status: 'open'
      };
      this.handleEnterTodo = this.handleEnterTodo.bind(this);
      this.handleStatus = this.handleStatus.bind(this);
      this.handleCreateTodo = this.handleCreateTodo.bind(this);
      this.handleClearTodos = this.handleClearTodos.bind(this);
      this.handleDeleteTodo = this.handleDeleteTodo.bind(this);
 
    }
    //Textbox Input handler
    handleEnterTodo(event) {
      
      this.setState({
        enterTodo: event.target.value
      });
    }
    //Status handler
    handleStatus(event) {
      let newStatus;
      const changeState = event.status == 'done' ? newStatus = 'open' : newStatus = 'done';
      
      //Verkürzen Copy State
      let todo = {
        ...event,
        status: newStatus
      };

      this.setState({ todo });
     
    }

    //delete todo
    handleDeleteTodo(event) {
      let todo = this.state.todos;
      todo.splice(this.state.todos.indexOf(event), 1)
    
      this.setState({ todo });
    }
   
    //Create Todo
    handleCreateTodo(event) {
      const todo = {
        id: this.state.todos.length,
        describtion: this.state.enterTodo,
        status: 'open'
      };

        this.setState({
          todos: [todo, ...this.state.todos]
        })
        this.state.enterTodo = emptyForm.enterTodo; // Überarbeiten
      
    }

    //Clear Todo List 
    handleClearTodos(event) {
      let CleanedTodos = []
      
      this.state.todos.forEach((element, index) => {

        if(this.state.todos[index].status == 'open'){
            CleanedTodos.push(this.state.todos[index]);
        } 
        
      });

      this.setState({ 
        todos: CleanedTodos
       });
    }

    render() {

      return (

        <>
          <InputBar

            handleCreateTodo={ this.handleCreateTodo }
            handleEnterTodo={ this.handleEnterTodo }
            enterTodo={ this.state.enterTodo }
            handleClearTodos={ this.handleClearTodos }
          />
          <Todo

            handleStatus={ this.handleStatus }
           
            todos={ this.state.todos }
            handleClearTodos={ this.state.handleClearTodos }
            handleDeleteTodo= { this.handleDeleteTodo }
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

Todo (Child);

```
import React from "react";
import { FormButton } from "./FormButton";


export class Todo extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const openTodo = [];
      const doneTodo = [];
      // just for develope
      const lineBreak = <hr></hr>
      

      //Select Open Todo and Done
      this.props.todos.forEach((element, index) => {
        if(this.props.todos[index].status == 'open'){
    
          let todoOpen = (
            //CSS Clases for design open 
            <div className="openTodos" key={this.props.todos[index].id.toString() }>
              
              {this.props.todos[index].describtion}
              <FormButton lable='' onClick= {() => this.props.handleStatus(this.props.todos[index])}/>
              <FormButton lable='' onClick= {() => this.props.handleDeleteTodo(this.props.todos[index])}/>
          
            </div>
          );
          //Push open Todo in Open Array
          openTodo.push(todoOpen); 
        } 
        else{
         
          let todoDone = (
            //CSS Clases for design open 
            <div className="openTodos" key={this.props.todos[index].id.toString() }>
          
              {this.props.todos[index].describtion}
              <FormButton lable='' onClick= {() => this.props.handleStatus(this.props.todos[index])}/>
              <FormButton lable='' onClick= {() => this.props.handleDeleteTodo(this.props.todos[index])}/>
      
            </div>
          );
          //Push done Todo in Done Array
          doneTodo.push(todoDone); 
        }

      });
      
      return <>
              {openTodo}
              {lineBreak}
              {doneTodo}
            </>;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not update the `todos` state. Your state is defined in `TodoTable` constructor as:

```js
this.state = {
   enterTodo: "",
   todos: this.props.todos,
   status: 'open'
};
```

But the state you update is **`todo`**, which is a new state property that wasn't assigned before.

```js
this.setState({ todo });
```

Before you made `handleStatus` immutable, the change worked because you changed the actual state object. Then it was reflected in the UI after `this.setState({ todo })` re-rendered the component.

`todo` object that you already have in `handleStatus` is the item in the `todos` array that has changed. Now, set the `todos` state with the changes.

**Edit:** here is a complete change in `handleStatus`. I added comments to clarify what I did. There are many ways to change an array immutably (you can also `splice` and find by index, or `map` a new array), I suggest here one way.

```js
handleStatus(changedTodo) {
   let newStatus = changedTodo.status == 'done' ? 'open' : 'done'; // It is more simple that way - you can assign newStatus directly.
   let todos = this.state.todos.slice(); // Create a copy of current state. A simple way to do immutable change.

   // Change todos state
   let todo = todos.find(i => i.id === changedTodo.id); // Find the changed object in the array

   if (todo) { // If object found, do the change
      todo = {
        ...todo,
        status: newStatus
      }
      this.setState({ todos }); // Update todos state
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I should change all "todo" in the handleStatatus to "todos" ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes but not only. Look at my edit